# Responsive image in a div responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm building my first actually decent website basically and I'm creating a background atm with some css and an image and I want to do it just as it is in the picture

[image].

(accomplished already) but it's not responsive probably because of position: absolute property and I want to make it properly responsive.

Here is the HTML code I am using for the background

```css
.bg {
  background: #9359C7;
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  height: 764px;
  width: 1280px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
}

.content img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: -178px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lol</h1>
    <img src="https://www.pikpng.com/pngl/m/69-698658_yami-ygi-y-gi-yu-gi-oh.png" alt="Yugi">
  </div>
</div>
```

- EDIT: I put my whole site on this [patebin](https://pastebin.com/2wemJwPy) since idk it wouldn't let me upload it on here the snippet I was given did not work for me at least.

Comment: That depends on what you want as mobile layout, but the general trick is not to use pixel, but percentages.

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please update to a [mcve]

Comment: your png with background. first, get rid of the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  padding: 40px 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 768px;
  background: #9359C7;
  padding: 20px;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 98%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: 10;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <header></header>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Lol</h1>
  </div>
  <img src="https://ms.yugipedia.com//c/c4/YamiYugi-DULI.png" alt="Yugi">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to do some fine tuning but this is basically it thank you very much!